# Combination of jekyll-redirect-from and github-metadata gems throwing errors

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I am working on a Jekyll site which uses `jekyll-redirect-from` to redirect old page URLs to their newer equivalents. It builds fine normally, but when I add the `GitHub-metadata` gem to my gemfile as well and attempt to build my site, I get a fairly unhelpful message:

```
> bundle exec jekyll build --trace
Configuration file: <site folder>/_config.yml
            Source: <site folder>
       Destination: <site folder>/_site
      Generating...
d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:67:in `join': no implicit conversion of Jekyll::GitHubMetadata::Value into String (TypeError)
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:67:in `redirect_url'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in generate_alt_urls'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:15:in `each'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:15:in `block in generate_alt_urls'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:13:in `each'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:13:in `generate_alt_urls'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.8.0/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:8:in `generate'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:251:in `block in generate'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:250:in `each'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:250:in `generate'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:45:in `process'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:55:in `build'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:33:in `process'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/bin/jekyll:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from d:/tools/Ruby21-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

The important part is the `no implicit conversion of Jekyll::GitHubMetadata::Value into String (TypeError)` section. It seems that somewhere the metadata gem is putting a custom object where the redirect gem expects there to be a string, and as a result it explodes.

If I remove all instances of anything referencing `site.github.*`, the error still occurs. But if I remove all `redirect_from`s, the error goes away and it builds successfully. I don't know enough about Ruby or either of these gems to do much troubleshooting past that. It looks like the culprit is [this line](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/blob/master/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb#L68) of `redirector.rb` in the Jekyll-redirect-from gem.

I have a repro site (very loose definition of "site") at [WasabiFan/curly-parakeet](https://github.com/WasabiFan/curly-parakeet). It throws the above error on both Windows and a fresh Ubuntu VM.

What might the problem be? Is there something that must be fixed in one of these gems?

P.S. As a result of this question, I have found a use for GitHub's suggested repo names. Thank you.

Comment: Not reproduced here. Did you have a repository with failing code ?

Comment: I do have a repo, but it's very large. When I get a chance I can make a copy of the core parts of it and push it to a test repo so you can repro it (hopefully) easily.

Comment: @DavidJacquel I just updated the question with a link to a confirmed repro case.

Comment: I also confirmed with this sample repo that it builds when on GitHub's servers. As I understand it, it ignores the `GitHub-metadata` gem and uses their own version when building there. Not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: Is it failing locally ?

Comment: Yes. It fails locally on both my normal Windows machine and a clean Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Still unable to reproduce (ubuntu 14.04, ruby 2.1.0 and 2.1.1-github). 
The failing code is in `jekyll-redirect-from::redirector.rb:67` clearly receives a `site.github.something`. How can it be ?

Comment: Running on a completely new install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I ran through the steps of installing Ruby 2.1.5 using RVM, cloning the test repo, installing the necessary gems and running a Jekyll build. I uploaded the full terminal log [here](https://gist.github.com/WasabiFan/5ab8fcfd51299782884f). Can you check this against what you're doing and what I should be doing? Also, we can't have much more back-and-forth in the comments here -- I think our options are SO chat or in an issue on my test repo on GitHub if you're interested in helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97105/discussion-between-david-jacquel-and-wasabi-fan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug report and they confirmed that this was a bug. I got it fixed in a [PR](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/pull/89).